# urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError error handled on one machine but not on another

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I have a weird issue. For the sake of having a short minimum working example (MWE), let's assume that `Connect()` returns a `urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection` object. Let's also assume that I have some other exceptions bubbling up that I want to ignore if `'magicword'` is found in the error message (not the actual word, but hey, this is a MWE).

**MWE:**

```
try:
    conn_obj = Connect()
except Exception as e:  # there are some other exceptions I want to ignore
    if 'magicword' not in e.message:
        print 'fatal error: {}'.format(e.message)
```

This works fine on my machine and prints 'fatal error' when encountered and ignores other exceptions (as it should in this case).

However, on a colleague's machine, the error isn't handled and instead crashes and creates a traceback. It's the exact same error on my machine, only his won't print and crashes instead of being handled. We both use the exact same OS (Windows 7).

Obviously not handling the specific exception isn't ideal, so I then tried that route:

```
from urllib3.exceptions import NewConnectionError

try:
    conn_obj = Connect()
except NewConnectionError as nce:
    print 'fatal error: {}'.format(e.message)
except Exception as e:  # there are some other exceptions I want to ignore
    if 'magicword' not in e.message:
        print 'fatal error: {}'.format(e.message)
```

That didn't work either. It won't catch the exception on his box for some reason. Why might the exception be handled on my machine but not on his?

**UPDATE:**

The connection object is raised inside the pyelasticsearch third party library. I've always been able to catch it just fine, but it is not being caught using the same code on others' machines. Here is a file I wrote to test if the error was caught when explicitly raised:

```
from urllib3.exceptions import NewConnectionError

def error_test(test_num):
    print '\n\n'
    try:
        if test_num == 1:
            print 'TEST 1: See if NewConnectionError is caught specifically'
            raise NewConnectionError('no pool', 'test one')
        elif test_num == 2:
            print 'TEST 2: See if RuntimeError is caught related to magicword'
            raise RuntimeError('test two magicword catching test')
        elif test_num == 3:
            print 'TEST 3: See if RuntimeError is caught NOT related to magicword'
            raise RuntimeError('test three')
    except NewConnectionError as nce:
        print 'Test 1 passed successfully.\n\n{}'.format(nce.message)
    except Exception as e:
        if 'magicword' not in e.message:
            print 'Test 3 passed successfully.\n\n{}'.format(e.message)
        else:
            print 'Test 2 passed successfully.\n\n{}'.format(e.message)

error_test(1)
error_test(2)
error_test(3)
```

This test worked perfectly on both of our machines. So somehow by getting the third-party library involved something is inconsistent between our machines (this is actually in a pyinstaller-compiled binary, so library differences shouldn't come into play).

Comment: can you provide traceback of your handled exc and colleague's one? Have you tried to print out e.message, catch BaseException...?

Comment: @kAlmAcetA the traceback is identical for both of us when I debugged it, only I can catch and handle the exception but his never gets caught. We are both running the same code.

Comment: to eliminate lib specific code run explicit `try: raise NewConnectionError('no pool', 'my magicword'); except Exception...`. Or even simpler `Exception` with message. does it work?

Comment: @kAlmAcetA sorry for the delay, I have to collaborate with the colleague and wrote a short script just to see if it caught those errors. It did. They were handled fine on both machines when I raised the error explicitly and handled it. The error is being raised through the pyelasticsearch library, but the exception that bubbles up is handled on my machine while not on his. It looks like I have A LOT of digging to do.

Comment: @kAlmAcetA I added my test code.

Comment: one more thing, it good to check if on colleague's pc you are in `except` anyway if you are - what is the message. If not it might be GeneratorExit, SystemExit

Comment: @kAlmAcetA I guess my issue is why it isn't being caught here. Shouldn't it just get passed through like it does on my machine, regardless of where in the chain the exception occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have tried `from elasticsearch.exceptions import ConnectionError` and replace your `NewConnectionError` with that. Docs from elasticsearch [here](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/exceptions.html)